# In what cases would a programmer be concerned with average time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

As a programmer, I always have asymptotic complexity in mind when implementing algorithms, but I have been trained to only care about “worst-case” time.  Anybody have any real-world examples of why average-time complexity is important? Thank you.

Comment: Quick sort has `O(n**2)` worst case and `O(n*log(n))` average case; *usually* quick sort is *faster* (has a smaller coefficient before `n * log(n)`)  then merge sort, but in some *degraged cases* (e.g. sorted array) quick sort is very slow - `O(n**2)`.

Comment: This is all about locality.. In computational geometry for example, there are many algorithms where the worst case is O(n^2), but are so rare in practice they're used in production code. You might want to look at this page for a working example (not by me): https://travellermap.com/tmp/delaunay.htm
Adding a point and doing triangulation requires to recompute all neighbors, so we could say the theoretical worst-case always requires to reprocess O(n - 1) neighbors at each insertion, thus O(n^2). Notice how that case 'never' happens ??!

Comment: I think it is good practice to always look at the worst case. Let's assume you can do something in guaranteed O(n log n) or in worst case O(n^2) but the latter is usually faster in practice. Now if it is crucial that the time is under some threshold you would certainly go for the first algorithm, on the other hand if you only care about speed and it doesn't matter if it will fail sometimes to solve in time or you have no time limit at all then you will probably go for the 2nd option.

Comment: `but I have been trained to only care about “worst-case” time` That's probably because it is easier to calculate. In the real world average case is what matters unless you are very latency sensitive. For example, using hash tables is considered very efficient for large datasets (if you have decent hash function), although its worst case seek time is `O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

You should always worry about average-case time complexity (unless the time is so little that it's not worth worrying about) but you also need to worry about worst-case time complexity unless:

- The probability of the worst-case is vanishingly small, and
- There is no possibility that an adversary will be able to trigger a worst case with a carefully tailored input.

There are cases where worst-case performance is only somewhat unlikely, not extremely unlikely. A classic case is a tree algorithm which assumes relatively balanced trees and fails catastrophically when presented with a left-biased tree, particularly if the biased tree is the result of a nit unlikely input (nearly sorted or reverse sorted data, for example). Those are cases where you should use a different algorithm even if it is slower in the average case.

But using slow algorithms to protect yourself from denial-of-service attacks is cutting off your nose to spite your face. To protect against DoS, it is sufficient to put a timer around the code and fail if the time is exceeded. (Or you could switch to a slower and safer algorithm to finish, which is effectively what introsort does, for example.)

In the real world asymptotic time is not a determining factor. Users don't patiently wait for O(n) seconds; they want results now, not now + cn for some constant *c*, particularly if *c* is big. That's especially true for logarithmic factors. In most cases, there is no effective difference between `log n` and 'log log n`, and often not even between`log n`and`n`. So don't go for the asymptotically "better" solution if that betterness involves a constant so big that the asymptote won't be approached with real-world problem sizes.

As an example, look at the various bignum multiplication algorithms. The asymptotically best algorithm known is so slow that it would only be advantageous on numbers so big that they won't fit in an average machine's memory. There are other, not quite so asymptotically superior algorithms which beat out naive multiplication on numbers with only hundreds of digits. Most good bignum packages implement two or three different algorithms, selecting heuristically based on number size.